# How to make an image link to an archive page with php/woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, attributes

I've created a custom field for adding a brand logo image to a product in woocommerce.  On the front end, the logo shows up at the start of the product summary - above the product title with this code:

```
/**Add MFG Logo Above Short Description*/

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'brands');

function brands() {
global $post;
global $product;


$mfglogo= get_post_meta($post->ID, 'brand_logo', true);

echo '<div>'; 
echo '<img src="' . $mfglogo.'"></a>';
echo'</div>';

}
```

I'd like to make this image linkable to the corresponding brands archive page.  I created a global attribute for brands as well so I can filter the products pages by brand.

I learned that you can make your attributes into a list on the front end, and they are clickable to their attribute archive pages with this code:

```
/**Add Brand Link to META List*/

function list_attributes( $product ) {

global $product;
global $post;

$attributes = $product->get_attributes();

if ( ! $attributes ) {

    return;

}

foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {

    // Get the taxonomy.
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product->id, $attribute[ 'name' ], 'all' );
    $taxonomy = $terms[ 0 ]->taxonomy;

    // Get the taxonomy object.
    $taxonomy_object = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy );

    // Get the attribute label.
    $attribute_label = $taxonomy_object->labels->name;

    // Display the label followed by a clickable list of terms.
    echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, $attribute[ 'name' ] , '<div class="attributes">' . $attribute_label . ': ' , ', ', '</div>' );
    break;

}

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end', 'list_attributes' );
```

.  How can I use this idea to make the logo image linkable???

Comment: Pro debugging tip: use `var_dump( $attriubute );` to see the contents of the array, and to understand the structure, so you can "zero in" on what part you need....

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm using it to print the information which helps.  Though, I'm still not sure which value/syntax to use out of the debugging...

Answer (score 0):

You could replace this:

```
echo '<div>'; 
echo '<a href="' . $attribute. '"><img src="' . $download4 .'"></a>';
echo'</div>';
```

with the following:

```
foreach ( $attribute as $attr) {

    echo '<div>'; 
    echo '<a href="#' . $attr->get_name(). '"><img src="' . $download4 .'"></a>';
    echo'</div>';

    // Uncomment the follwing line if you want to display the first attribute only (makes sense since you only have one logo image)
    // break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet.  Unfortunately it produces a catachable fatal error.  'Object of class could not be convertered to string....

Comment: please use 'var_dump($attr)' inside the loop and let me know what it returns

Comment: object(WC_Product_Attribute)#2019 (1) { ["data":protected]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> int(10) ["name"]=> string(8) "pa_brand" ["options"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(184) } ["position"]=> int(0) ["visible"]=> bool(false) ["variation"]=> bool(false) } }

Catchable fatal error: Object of class WC_Product_Attribute could not be converted to string

Comment: The first section is the var_dump output.

Comment: I edited the code to reflect the attribute name as the link. Just note that you have not provided enough information about the needed output, or what you're planning to do exactly, so this might not work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I see what your updated code is doing.  It's creating a link for the global attribute name.  What I need is to create a link of the value of that global attribute where "brand" is the global attribute name, and "mfg1" is the value - thus linking to that brands archive page.

Comment: You're approaching this in the wrong why, how do you link an attribute to an archive page, because there is no reference in the attribute object to the data you're trying to display?

Comment: Yes i'm starting to believe that.  It has to be something with the 'terms' of the taxonomy object.  When I look at the loop in the reference code above that I posted from tutsplus, it shows the loop getting the term and taxonomy object as the link.  I just can't get the syntax correct...

Comment: Sorry but you'll need to update your question and provide enough information if you want help to sort this issue, until now it's still unclear what you're trying to do. Attributes don't have a url by default.

Comment: Okay I tried to rewrite the question.  I don't want to be too vague, but I also don't want it to sound complicated...I want to link the image to the archive page which is derived from the global attribute - 'Brand'